# How to see the data content sending back from server using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Main.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Lesson 21: Easy AJAX Calls with jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Lesson 21: Easy AJAX Calls with jQuery load()</h1>      
    <p><a href="#">Click here to fetch HTML content</a></p>     
    <div id="result">       
    </div>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()        
        {   
            var url = "lesson18_test.xml";  
            function processData(data)      
                {       
                    var resultStr = "";
                    var items = $(data).find('language');
                    $(items).each(function(i)       
                        {
                            resultStr += $(this).text() + '<br />';     
                            $('#result').html(resultStr);       
                        });     
        }       
    $('a').click(function()     
                    {   
                        $.get(url, processData);        
                    });     
        });     
    </script>           
    </body>
    </html>
```

lesson18_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<languages>
<language>PHP</language>
<language>Ruby On Rails</language>
<language>C#</language>
<language>JavaScript</language>
</languages>
```

Above code is from one tutorial here: http://www.html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson21.php

Question:

Is there a way that i can see the content in data? I tried `alert(data)`, it only shows ' object XMLobject'. I know inside data is the lesson18_test.xml, but just want to see how it structured in data.

Comment: alerts will only show you the entire data if you try it on `data`. try going further, like `$(data).find('language:first').text()`

Comment: alternatively, you could use breakpoints and check there. your entire xml data will lie in `innerText` property i think (not very sure)

Comment: Why not use your browser's developer's tools, like Chrome's Developer Tools, or Firebug in FireFox? You can see the contents of the variable, and the actual message sent on the network.

Comment: Travaling Tech Guy is right. Try to use one of the mentioned tool or plugin. You can also download and install Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) , which is must have http debugger for every web developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object to get `responseXML` or `responseText` properties as given below

```
$(document).ready(function()   {   
    var url = "lesson18_test.xml";  
    function processData(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {       
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
        var resultStr = "";
        var items = $(data).find('language');
        $(items).each(function(i)       
                      {
                          resultStr += $(this).text() + '<br />';     
                          $('#result').html(resultStr);       
                      });     
    }       
    $('a').click(function()     
                 {   
                     $.get(url, processData);        
                 });     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find the usage of $.ajax easier (I do, offers more freedom customizing it, matter of personal preference):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url:  "/asdfasdf",
    data: "foo=bar&name=cookiemonster",        
    // alternatively: data: { foo: "bar", name: "cookiemonster" },

    timeout: 5000, /* 5sec */

    success: function(data)
    {
    },
    error: function(fa,il,ure)
    {
          // yay error handler
         alert(fa + "\n" + il + "\n" + ure);
    },
    statuscode: { 404: function() { alert('Not found'); /* another way to handle errors */ }  

});
```

Comment: if you ever come across a code block containing `try { to(); } catch (em) { /* all */ }`, that's my hidden signature. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert(data.responsetext)` this will show you the data without being constructed to an object